# Could not create /home/ajidaribawa/.vnc

Tags: software-installation

I entered command

> tightvncserver :1

and then the terminal showing

```
tightvncserver: Could not create /home/ajidaribawa/.vnc.
```

help me thx :D

Comment: From which user are you trying to connect?

Answer (score 2):

When using VNC , it's going to expect that your home directory is writable. You'll need to create a user with a writable home directory to run VNC.

Once this is done you should be able to start VNC normally.
now check use using VNC have write permission in the /home/ajidaribawa dir

Comment: so.... i need to useradd vnc-user  ???

Comment: simply do mkdir /home/$USER